# Is scrolling down Facebook web page causes high CPU usage normal?

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome, facebook, intel-cpu

[image: Google Chrome task manager snapshot]

- CPU: Intel i5-2400
- RAM: 8GB (dual channel)
- No graphic card

I've tried the command below but it didn't work for me.

```
sudo echo > "options drm_kms_helper poll=N" > /etc/modprobe.d/local.conf
```

Please can you guys help me solve this problem?

[Does Facebook page in new tab share the same CPU resource with others?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXxRr.png)

If this is true, how to separete them from using the same distributed CPU resource?

The information below retrieved by command line `sudo '/usr/bin/intel_gpu_top'` when I keep pressing page down button on the keyboard in browsing Faceook web page for testing the GPU status.

```
 render busy:  12%: ██▌                                    render space: 12/131072
            bitstream busy:   0%:                                     bitstream space: 0/131072
              blitter busy:   1%: ▎                                     blitter space: 0/131072

                      task  percent busy
                        CS:  11%: ██▎                     vert fetch: 7542782 (1686/sec)
                       GAM:  11%: ██▎                     prim fetch: 2756058 (592/sec)
                     EU 00:  11%: ██▎                  VS invocations: 7512722 (1683/sec)
                     EU 10:  11%: ██▎                  GS invocations: 0 (0/sec)
                     EU 11:  11%: ██▎                       GS prims: 0 (0/sec)
                       PSD:  11%: ██▎                  CL invocations: 2738436 (590/sec)
                     EU 01:  11%: ██▎                       CL prims: 2746022 (591/sec)
                     EU 12:  11%: ██▎                  PS invocations: 462796763240 (101142779/sec)
                     EU 02:  11%: ██▎                  PS depth pass: 462802984040 (101142779/sec)
                        IZ:  11%: ██▎                  
                        SC:  11%: ██▎                  
                       HIZ:  11%: ██▎                  
                      WMFE:  11%: ██▎                  
                        MT:  11%: ██▎                  
                       SVG:  11%: ██▎                  
                      WMBE:  11%: ██▎                  
                     RCPFE:  10%: ██                   
                     RCPBE:  10%: ██                   
                       RCC:  10%: ██                   
                       DAP:  10%: ██                   
                        PL:   8%: █▋                   
                      IC 0:   8%: █▋                   
                      IC 1:   8%: █▋                   
                        TD:   8%: █▋                   
                        SO:   8%: █▋                   
                        SI:   7%: █▌                   
                        FL:   7%: █▌                   
                      SVRW:   7%: █▌                   
                        FT:   6%: █▎                   
                        DG:   6%: █▎                   
                      SVSM:   5%: █                    
                        QC:   5%: █                    
                        DM:   3%: ▋                    
                        SF:   0%:                      
                        CL:   0%:                      
                       ISC:   0%:                      
                       VS0:   0%:
```

Comment: Does this occur all the time when using Facebook or only when scrolling?

Comment: It always exists.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, it is normal. Rendering web pages with lots of graphics (photos) is a heavy task in Chrome.

This happens mostly with low-end graphics adapters, like your built in Intel.

Comment: I tried using intel_gpu_top to monitor the loading, but no item seems to be loaded 100% instead of CPU statues.

Comment: That is the problem. GPU can't do some tasks and CPU is loaded.

Comment: Is it possible to solve or boost the performance without buying a graphic card?

Comment: I do not think it is possible.

Comment: You can upgrade to 16.04. There is  small chance that new mesa performs better.

Answer (score 0):

In Firefox you can disable "smooth scrolling" which saves RAM and CPU. I don't use Chrome very often, so I don't know how to disable it there, but it should be possible.

[image: Firefox Kubuntu 16.04]

Comment: @stackuser did it lower the cpu usage?

Comment: No, I disable it each time after installing google chrome.    This only matches my habit, I hate smooth scrolling.

Comment: @stackuser did you try another browser?

Comment: Yes, Firefox is much more slow than Google-Chrome while browsing facebook.

Comment: If there is a method to make Firefox faster, I would never use google-chrome due to image sharpness display of thumbernail-zoom addon.

Comment: @stackuser I have seen, that modern browser waste so much resources, because they normally can do it on normal PCs. You could try another browser, maybe Konquerer (but according to ssllabs.com it's insecure). Or try Noscript and block unnessesary content to improve the performance

Comment: I found firefox multi-process function makes browsing faster, but all add-ons should be disabled.